# pygame load image error when encountering chinese path

Tags: python

How can I load an image named in chinese in pygame? I just get an `error: Couldn't open f:\python\image\��ɫ.jpg.` when I use `pygame.image.load` method.

Comment: Change your system font to Chinese. It may help event it is not very convenient.

Comment: My system font is already chinese.

Comment: I have solved the problem by using encode and decode method.Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Just rename the file, it should be the easiest way to fix your problem